# Are animals depicted as talking in Rig Veda outside of mandala X?

Tags: rig-veda, identification-request, animals

In Ramayana, hanuman speaks chaste Sanskrit to Sita. Jambavan, jatayu et al are also able to talk.  As far as I know this is a post-rigvedic development. An  Indo-European parallel is Hector's horse talking to him in the Iliad.

Comment: There is no indo-european parallel here, almost all cultures have stories of animals talking. Do you really like inserting indo european/aryan into every question?

Comment: You have changed the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As for as I know, animals are depicted as talking in Rig Veda at some occasions but only in Mandala 10. In [Rig Veda, 10.108](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10108.htm) Sarama, the celestial bitch and messenger of Lord Indra, talked with Panis.

> 1. WHAT wish of Saramā hath brought her hither? The path leads far away to distant places.
>      What charge hast thou for us? Where turns thy journey? How hast thou made thy way o’er Rasā's waters.
>
> 2 I come appointed messenger of Indra, seeking your ample stores of wealth, O Paṇis.
>   This hath preserved me from the fear of crossing: thus have I made my way o’er Rasā's waters.

Rig Veda also mention Vrishakapi, the ape friend of Lord Indra at some places like [RV 10.86](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv10086.htm). Also the twin Ashvins have lot of Suktas dedicated who are said to have horse head.

Comment: thanks - mandala X is very different from other mandalas - are there any examples from earlier mandalas?

Comment: @SK Vrishakapi and Ashvins are mentioned outside Mandala 10 but it is not explicitly mentioned that they are talking something.

Comment: if you would be so kind as to confirm or deny that only examples occur in mandala X I would accept the answer.  I Think "ashvin" means "horseman" and not someone with a horses's head. @Triyugi Narayan Mani

Comment: @SK you are right about Ashvins but some times they are depicted as having horse head. I will edit the answer.